# How to change output format of material 2 date-picker

Tags: angular, datepicker, momentjs, angular-material2

I am using angular material 2 [Date-Picker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) component

The only string input it understands is in ISO date format

Ex. "2017-11-13T10:39:28.300Z"

But i want to patch my form control with locale date value

Ex. "11/13/2017, 4:09:46 PM"

So that it output the later format and even expects this format.

How can i do this? Is there a way to not use ISO but custom formats?

Some Thoughts:

Should i write customDateAdaptor?

Update:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-moment-adapter-example-bqvm2f

i have tried to implement custom dateAdaptor by extending nativeDateAdaptor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best solution would be to use ControlValueAccessor and make a custom input component, this will have you in control of input and output of the component.

update:

Here is the reference implementation using this approach reproduced by Moutaz-homsi

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dlxnmx?file=app%2Fcva-date.component.ts

Comment: Good stuff from @Ankit Raonka. This works very well.

Comment: Sorry but it's not working when you type the date from input, the date picker work but not your input.

Comment: I have a similar problem and since this answer has input problems, I've asked it again at https://stackoverflow.com/q/66072525/4321097

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a class extending NativeDateAdapter (from "@angular/material/core")

If you override the format function you will change the way the date is displayed on the input after selecting a date.
The parse function is called when you edit the input value manually, to display a valid date.

See the 2nd comment for more details: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5722

**EDIT:**

I couldn't find a way to format the output so I've wrapped the material datepicker component to a custom component.

This custom component has a 2 way binding on a property to get the date:
`@Input() selectedValue` and `@Output() selectedValueChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();`

A `private _selectedValue;` is set on ngInit, it will contain the datepicker date.

Then in the template, the html datepicker input element has `[(ngModel)]="_selectedValue" (dateChange)="onChange($event)"`

The `onChange` function gets the datepicker value `_selectedValue`, formats it and emit it to `selectedValueChange`.

The final component looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import {
  DateAdapter,
  NativeDateAdapter,
  MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
  MAT_DATE_LOCALE
} from "@angular/material/core";
import * as moment from "moment";

const CUSTOM_DATE_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: { month: "short", year: "numeric", day: "numeric" }
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: "input",
    monthYearLabel: { year: "numeric", month: "short" },
    dateA11yLabel: { year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" },
    monthYearA11yLabel: { year: "numeric", month: "long" }
  }
};
const dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";
// date adapter formatting material2 datepickers label when a date is selected
class AppDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
  format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
    if (displayFormat === "input") {
      return moment(date).format(dateFormat);
    } else {
      return date.toDateString();
    }
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: "datepicker",
  templateUrl: "./datepicker.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./datepicker.component.scss"],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: CUSTOM_DATE_FORMATS },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: AppDateAdapter }
  ]
})
export class DatepickerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() placeholder;
  @Output() onFilter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input() selectedValue;
  @Output() selectedValueChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  private _selectedValue;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._selectedValue = this.selectedValue;
  }

  onChange($event) {
    this.selectedValue = this.updateDate($event.value);
    this.onFilter.emit(this.selectedValue);
  }

  updateDate(date) {
    let formatedDate;
    if (date !== undefined) {
      formatedDate = moment(date).format(dateFormat);
    }
    this.selectedValueChange.emit(formatedDate);
    return formatedDate;
  }
}
```

Comment: i have done exactly that, but format is just for showing the value in ur format i want the output of the form to be in some format other than iso. this.myform.value give me date in iso string

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do that so I've wrapped the datepicker into a custom component. Please see the edited answer above

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, if you are already doing this but I found some information that might give you some idea on your implementation.

As of today the `Angular Material Date Module` supports two ways of providing a date value `MatNativeDateModule` and `MatMomentDateModule`. The `MatNativeDateModule` accepts `ISO 8601` format by default. But since you don't want to use `ISO` format, I would suggest using `MatMomentDateModule` (Moment.js implementation).

When we use the `MatMomentDateModule` the date object is not anymore a JavaScript `Date` object but instead is a `Moment.js instance`(take advantage of methods available to a Moment js instance like `format()`). There are basic to intermediate examples available on Material Date Picker docs page using the Moment.js. Also, once your date is a Moment.js instance, you could overwrite the methods(format, parse.) from [MomentDateAdapter](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/material-moment-adapter/adapter/moment-date-adapter.ts) instead of native date adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to write a completely new adapter or use the moment adapter. `@angular/material-moment-adapter:5.0.0-rc0`. The moment adapter uses momentjs and allows you much more control on the output format.

Moment is also able to parse different input formats.

The `NativeDateAdapter` uses the [Intl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) to format the output date. You can try to provide a custom [MAT_NATIVE_DATE_FORMATS](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/datetime/native-date-formats.ts) instance but I am not sure how far this gets you.

**EDIT**

You are currently using 2.0.0-beta12 of angular/material, that doesn't fit with your code based on 5.0.0-rc0/master. There are changes in the codebase, especially the deserialize function which is not present in 2.0.0-beta12, that's why it is not being called. If you can't update to angular 5 then look at `MatDatepickerInput.setValue/coerceDateProperty` which sets the date into your `FormControl`.

Comment: I want to use this datepicker for lets say birthdate. The output is in UTC so the birthdate will change based onwhere your server is. The output shouldnt be timezone aware as birthdate cant change. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: @AnkitRaonka see my edit, that is your current problem I believe

Answer (score 0):

you can call Emitter of this module (for example click event) and change model binded to this module to secondary model.

Answer (score 0):

First import moment and set format .
https://momentjs.com/

```
 import * as moment from 'moment';

setDateFormat(date) {
    this.myDate = moment(date).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very easy solution.

1. Use a custom date adaptor

```
// create date.helpers.ts

import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NativeDateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';

export const PICK_FORMATS = {
    parse: { dateInput: { month: 'short', year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' } },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'input',
        monthYearLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'short' },
        dateA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' },
        monthYearA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long' }
    }
};

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PickDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
    format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
        if (displayFormat === 'input') {
            return formatDate(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy', this.locale);;
        } else {
            return date.toDateString();
        }
    }
}
```

add this to

```
// your.module.ts

 providers: [
    NomineeService,
    { provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { appearance: 'legacy' } },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: PickDateAdapter },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: PICK_FORMATS },
  ]
```

2. Custom Javascript date function to convert ISODate to readable string

```
//shared.service.ts
formatDate(date): string {
    const _date = new Date(date);
    const day = _date.getDate();
    const month = _date.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = _date.getFullYear();
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
  }

  formatTime(date: Date): string {
    const _date = new Date(date);
    const hours = _date.getHours()
    const minutes = _date.getMinutes();
    const seconds = _date.getSeconds();
    return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  }

  toDateTimestamp(date: Date): string {
    const dateStamp = this.formatDate(date);
    const timeStamp = this.formatTime(date);
    return `${dateStamp} ${timeStamp}`
  }
  calculateDays(fromDate, toDate): number {
    const FromDate = new Date(fromDate);
    const ToDate = new Date(toDate);
    const difference = ToDate.getTime() - FromDate.getTime();
    const days = Math.round((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
    return days;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

you can change it's format like this:

```
 const Date = Date.replace(/-/g, '/')
```