# Angular material datepicker - select date only

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, date-formatting

I have a Material Datepicker from which I would like to only get date with no timestamp. Since my timezone is GMT+2, API always receives something like 03.04.2018 22:00:00 UTC, but I would like to save the dates in local.

My datepicker: "Wed Apr 11 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)"

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="start" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" formControlName="start" name="start" >
    <div class="date__picker__button">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="start"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #start [disabled]="!formulationForm.enabled"></mat-datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is possible to format the datepicker value before calling API but I was hoping there is a better solution.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262449/how-to-change-output-format-of-material-2-date-picker

Comment: Thanks @SuvethanNantha, I made it work with the component from the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are 2 ways that I know works.

1. Using a date adaptor. You can use this as a service or a global function.

```
// date.helpers.ts

import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NativeDateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';

export const PICK_FORMATS = {
    parse: { dateInput: { month: 'short', year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' } },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'input',
        monthYearLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'short' },
        dateA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' },
        monthYearA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long' }
    }
};

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PickDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
    format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
        if (displayFormat === 'input') {
            return formatDate(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy', this.locale);;
        } else {
            return date.toDateString();
        }
    }
}
```

```
// add this to your.module.ts

providers: [
    NomineeService,
    { provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { appearance: 'legacy' } },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: PickDateAdapter },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: PICK_FORMATS },
  ]
```

2. Using a user-defined function which converts ISODate to a readable date.

```
// shared.service.ts

formatDate(date): string {
    const _date = new Date(date);
    const day = _date.getDate();
    const month = _date.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = _date.getFullYear();
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
  }

  formatTime(date: Date): string {
    const _date = new Date(date);
    const hours = _date.getHours()
    const minutes = _date.getMinutes();
    const seconds = _date.getSeconds();
    return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  }

  toDateTimestamp(date: Date): string {
    const dateStamp = this.formatDate(date);
    const timeStamp = this.formatTime(date);
    return `${dateStamp} ${timeStamp}`
  }
  calculateDays(fromDate, toDate): number {
    const FromDate = new Date(fromDate);
    const ToDate = new Date(toDate);
    const difference = ToDate.getTime() - FromDate.getTime();
    const days = Math.round((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
    return days;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `moment` library of node.js:

```
npm i moment --save
```

After that you can do this;

```
let formatted_date = moment(var_to_format).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```